# I have installed tensorflow but I am facing proplem

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shashe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you trying to install ? There are many questions and answers here about this issue that you can search.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan TensorFlow 2.3.1 and I roll it down to TensorFlow 2.3.0 but I am facing the same problem

Comment: Why don't you use a Anaconda environment ? `conda create -n tensorflow23python37-gpu python=3.7
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I am already using anaconda environment by pip install TensorFlow

Comment: What is the version of python ? Does it match the Tf version ?

Comment: yes it much it is 3.7.6 compatible with TF 2.2 and above

Comment: Is your machine a 32 bit or 64 bit machine? What version of windows are you using. Generally this error is more a problem of your windows rather than a tensorflow issue. Try installing `Service Pack for Microsoft Windows` and try again

Comment: @negus Is your issue resolved now? Else ensure that you have [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) installed and also check the system requirements as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements.). Thanks!